# How to find matching frame for a prestored reference Image in a Video using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, matching, surf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [OpenCV match template not scoring well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2308592/opencv-match-template-not-scoring-well)

I have stored a video file and need to check each frames for matching with already prestored Image file .. I have used cvQueryFrame , from that createImage for frame to image conversion , and checking this image X with prestored image file image Y suing Template matching ... But could not get desired result ? any combination of SURF or SIFT or Line detection algorithms should be used ?

Comment: or even: [matchTemplate finding good match](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520882/matchtemplate-finding-good-match)

Answer (score 0):

no need to do create image....

```
IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame();
```

will give you the image in IplImage form...template matching is just corelation...it might not give you correct matching always...if you are using OpenCV 2.4.2 there then you can use FREAK,ORB,SIFT,SURF for matching your pre-stored image with your video frame...here is the [**link**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your "prestored" image is part of the video, you can simply compute the difference (e.g. cv::norm) between the frames and your image.
If you are looking to find an image which is "similar to" a given query image, then it is a very different topic, and there are a lot of academic articles on this subject.